# Sharepoint list column to find the status changed time

Tags: list, workflow, sharepoint-addin

I have three states like ready,inprogress,closed.

when the status is changed to inprogress or closed and saved, is there a way to get the time when the status is changed in a separate column automatically similar to created time or modified time?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box there is no such column exists.

The easiest way to handle this situation is using a SharePoint Designer workflow.

1. Add three date columns to the list.
2. Create a workflow which update the respective date field based on the status value.